# Access MDB database. Linux: how to get a very odd pattern from the DB?

Tags: linux, ms-access

I'm in a VERY difficult problem.

I have a Microsoft Access Data Base, but it was made in the most chaotic way possible. The DB has like 150+ tables, Only uses like 50% of the tables. The relations are almost random. But, somehow, it delivers some information.

I need to get a particular component of the DB, but is so tangled that I can not manage to get into the table that creates that value. I revised every table, one by one, and found nothing.

I used mdbtools for Linux to try to inspect with more details the DB. But unfortunately has not been developed in years, and it closes every time. Maybe because the DB is "big" ? -700 mg-

I'm wondering: is there a way to see all the relations the arrives to the particular value I'm looking? Or to decompile the DB? I have no idea in which language it was made. I'm suspecting that it was made in Visual, just because is rather crappy.

Well, waiting for some help.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Access installed so you can use a GUI to review the database and the relationships window?  Probably not as you mention Linux in your subject and tags.   That would still be my suggestion though.

Comment: I have the .mdb file. But only working on Linux. Nevertheless, I checked in a windows machine using M. Access, but it was incredible messy the relations. Really, is a mess :S

Comment: Ok, explain more what you mean by "get a particular component of the DB".   Is this using a query? Or what?

Comment: There is no magic formula to tell you where a table value comes from.  check the code behind the forms, check if there are macro's firing, or any update/append queries, any cascading relationships, ect.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using (still) MS Access for this. But, if relationships look messy on the diagram, you can query one of the *system* tables (**MSysRelationships**) directly to get ALL the relationships you need (e.g. for particular table etc.):

[image]

To unhide system tables in early versions of Access (97-2003), follow the instructions [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/database/view_systables.php):

For Access 2007, do the following:
[image]